# 'Nan' after group by and string concatenation on pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like this:

```
name  | weekday | count 
Peter | Friday  | {16, 17, 9, 10, 15}
Peter | Friday  | {10, 11, 14}  
Peter | Friday  | {16, 17, 11, 12, 15}  
Bob   | Friday  | {10}
Bob   | Friday  | {9, 10, 11, 12, 13}
Bob   | Friday  | {9, 10, 11, 14, 15}
```

I want to group by name and weekday, add a new column of intersection of `count` like this:

```
name  | weekday | intersection 
Peter | Friday  | 
Bob   | Friday  | 10
```

where empty string should be returned for no intersection situation, here's the code I'm using:

```
df.groupby(['name','weekday']).apply(lambda x: pd.Series({'intersection': ", ".join("{0}".format(n) for n in sorted(list(set.intersection(*x['count']))))})).reset_index()
```

But I'm getting result like this:

```
name  | weekday | intersection 
Peter | Friday  | Nan
Bob   | Friday  | 10
```

I've tried `''.join()` on empty list and it worked and returned empty string, but it won't work after using the group by, I have no idea why it's doing this and how to solve it

Comment: My dataframe is actually larger than the example, and for some other rows while the intersection is empty it would return the empty string instead of Nan, any ideas why it's doing that?

Comment: you can just `fillna` with `''` afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Find the intersection via [reduce](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functools.html#functools.reduce), "stringify" and join:

```py
from functools import reduce

def get_intersection(s: pd.Series) -> str:
    intersect = reduce(lambda a, b: a.intersection(b), s.iloc[1:], s.iat[0])
    return ', '.join([str(x) for x in intersect])

intersection = (df.groupby(['name', 'weekday'])['count']
                  .agg(get_intersection)
                  .rename('intersection')
                  .reset_index()
                 )
```

which gives you:

```py
print(intersection)

    name    weekday intersection
0   Bob     Friday  10
1   Peter   Friday
```

if you're dealing with large datasets with little overlap, a `while len(intersect) > 0` loop would probably be better than `reduce` for avoiding unnecessary processing/work